# If $f$ is integrable and bounded over $[\delta,1]$ for all $\delta \in (0,1]$ then is $f$ integrable over all of $[0,1]$ $?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$  be  bounded and  *integrable*  on  $(\delta,1]$ . Is  $f$  integrable  on  $[0,1]$ $?$

I  thought  of  the  function  ${1}\over  {x}$  which  could  satisfy  the   condition  and  prove  in  negative  only  it  is  not  bounded  on  $[0,1]$  ,  in  fact  not  even  defined  at  $0$ .

I'm unsure where to go from here. 
Thanks.

Comment: do you mean $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @Surb : A little  elaboration  please.   Thank  you.

Comment: Surb, please post it as an answer :)

Comment: It depends. Is $f$ bounded on $[0,1]$ and integrable on every $(\delta,1]$, or is it (bounded and integrable) on each $(\delta,1]$? The question isn't clear.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi  :  Either  case  is  possible,I  don't  know.How  does  that  make  dfifferences ? Please  elaborate  in  comment  or  post  in  answer .

Comment: Integrable in the sense of the Riemann or Lebesgue (or etc.) integral?

Answer (score 5):

Let $M$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Let $F(x)=\int_x^1 |f(x)|dx$ with $0<x<1$. The function $F$ is nonincreasing and bounded since 
$$0\leq F(x)\leq M\int_0^1dx=M,$$
therefore it converges.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain ?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is positive: *if $f$ is integrable over $[\delta,1]$ for all $\delta \in (0,1]$ then $f$ is integrable over $[0,1]$.*

Following is a proof using Riemann integration.

Take $\epsilon > 0$. By hypothesis $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$, so you can find $M > 0$ with $\vert f(x) \vert \le M$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Take $\delta= \frac{\epsilon}{4M}$. As $\delta > 0$ and $f$ is supposed to be integrable on $[\delta,1]$, you can find two step functions $s,S$ defined on $[\delta,1]$ with $$s(x) \le f(x) \le S(x) \text{ and } \int_\delta^1 (S(x)-s(x)) dx \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Then extends $s,S$ on $[0,1]$ by defining $s(x)=-M$ and $S(x)=+M$ for $x \in [0,\delta)$. You have $s(x) \le f(x) \le S(x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$, $s,S$ are steps functions and $$\int_0^1 (S(x)-s(x)) dx = \int_0^\delta (S(x)-s(x)) dx + \int_\delta^1 (S(x)-s(x)) dx \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} +\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$

As this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, you can conclude that $f$ is Riemmann (hence Lebesgue) integrable on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is integrable in $[\frac{1}{n},1]$ for every $n$, so the set of descontinuities $C_n$, on $[\frac{1}{n},1]$ has zero measure. Therefore, the set of descontinuities on $[0,1]$ has zero measure and since $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ you have that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: First sentence is incorrect I think. Or am I wrong?

Comment: $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable iff the set of its descontinuities has zero measure.

Comment: that is criterion for Riemann integrability... What about $f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ (everywhere discontinuous, yet Lebesgue integrable)?

Comment: My hypotesis is $f$ Riemann integrable.

Comment: I assumed integrable=Lebesgue integrable. OP should specify this.